# MySQL Tables and C# General Design Question

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I need to port lots of data to MySQL within few days. So far I kept all my data in classes then json it to txt file. My basic set up is:

```
> IList<MainClass> mainData = new List<MainClass>(); MainClass oneItem =
> new MainClass();

> MainClass consists of other Classes and Lists, such as:
> IList<SubClass> subData = new List<SubClass>(); // subData contains
> numerical values & strings.
```

So, for each job, I'd create new instance of MainClass, populate it and store it in IList.

I have tried to replicate MainClass in MySQL but I'm not sure if I got the general SQL idea correct.

There is no relationship between SubClasses (they're used individually to store parts of data). Let's say for now I don't need relationships between SubClasses

subData IList contains let say 2 instances of another Class, say, element

```
Table: MainClass
    id_main
    name
    dateCreated
    userCreated
...

Table: SubClassOne
    id_subClass (increment, unique)
    id_mainClass
    id_order
    sting var1
    sting var2
    sting var3
    DateTime var 4
    DateTime var 5
    ...

Table: SubClassTwo
    id_subClass (increment, unique)
    id_mainClass
    id_order
    data
```

To populate the DB i did:

```
MainClass oneItem = new MainClass(); // populate all etc.
```

- Insert oneItem to Table MainClass (insert only relevant data). ID is auto increment
- Get last Insert ID
- Insert subData elemnt1 to Table SubClassOne
  id_mainClass = last Insert ID from MainClass Table
  id_order = subData position in IList (1 for first element etc. Order is important).

Table: SubClassOne will look something like:

```
    id_subClass   id_mainClass  id_order sting var1 ...
         1                1           1         element_1 var
         2                1           2         element_1 var
         3                1           3         element_1 var
         4                1           4         element_1 var
         5                1           1         element_2 var
         6                1           2         element_2 var
         7                1           3         element_2 var
         8                1           4         element_2 var
         9                2           1         element_1 var
         10               2           2         element_1 var
         11               2           3         element_1 var
         12               2           4         element_1 var
         13               2           1         element_2 var
         14               2           2         element_2 var
```

Does this seems ok?

thanks.

Comment: Define "ok". Did it work, and produce what you expected, or not? Only you can answer that. (But if you don't know what you're aiming for, then you'll never succeed.) If you have another specific concern, please explain it.

Comment: Hi,I've just tested the read and I have all data I needed. My concern is should I be storing data in the same table (eg. SubClassOne ) with linked keys pointing to individual MainClass, or should I create new Tables each time I add MainClass. I have ~ 800k of MainClass ...

Comment: If the MainClass data always has the same structure then it should be one table. Likewise if you add data for SubClassOne multiple times that should always be in one table. As a general rule in SQL table design, if you find you have two tables with the same fields in them, then it should all be in one table. Otherwise the design is de-normalised. Did you study anything about relational database design before you started working on this?

Comment: Thanks, looks like I did the Tables correctly then. I haven't done anything with relations yet, i will have to read about it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write to multiple tables at once, e.g. write mainClass (auto Inc ID), then write to 6 other tables data using mainClass ID. So far I write mainClass, get last ID entry, then loop for each table subClass and populate it using that ID. Performance is very low. For reading I'm fine, I'm reading multiple tables at once with using the keys/operators.

Comment: "So far I write mainClass, get last ID entry, then loop for each table subClass and populate it using that ID"...it's true it's not very quick but if you need to use the new ID from each row then unfortunately that's how it ends up